# How can i deserialize this JSON

Tags: java, android, json

This is my **JSON** data i want to parse but am still new in deserialization, i want to get the following Attributes from this **JSON data** :

1.*AirportCode*.

2.*Latutude*.

3.*Longitude*.

This is the **JSON** containing two lists of the Airports.

```
{
    "AirportResource": {
        "Airports": {
            "Airport": [{
                "AirportCode": "AAL",
                "Position": {
                    "Coordinate": {
                        "Latitude": 57.09305556,
                        "Longitude": 9.85
                    }
                },
                "CityCode": "AAL",
                "CountryCode": "DK",
                "LocationType": "Airport",
                "Names": {
                    "Name": [{
                        "@LanguageCode": "xx",
                        "$": "Aalborg"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "de",
                        "$": "Aalborg"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "ru",
                        "$": "Ольборг"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "pt",
                        "$": "Aalborg"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "jp",
                        "$": "オールボア"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "kr",
                        "$": "올보르그"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "en",
                        "$": "Aalborg"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "it",
                        "$": "Aalborg"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "fr",
                        "$": "Aalborg"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "es",
                        "$": "Aalborg"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "ka",
                        "$": "奧爾堡"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "pl",
                        "$": "Aalbork"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "mi",
                        "$": "奥尔堡"
                    }]
                },
                "UtcOffset": 2,
                "TimeZoneId": "Europe\/Copenhagen"
            }, {
                "AirportCode": "AAR",
                "Position": {
                    "Coordinate": {
                        "Latitude": 56.30388889,
                        "Longitude": 10.62
                    }
                },
                "CityCode": "AAR",
                "CountryCode": "DK",
                "LocationType": "Airport",
                "Names": {
                    "Name": [{
                        "@LanguageCode": "xx",
                        "$": "Aarhus"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "en",
                        "$": "Aarhus"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "de",
                        "$": "Aarhus"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "it",
                        "$": "Aarhus"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "fr",
                        "$": "Aarhus"
                    }, {
                        "@LanguageCode": "es",
                        "$": "Aarhus"
                    }]
                },
                "UtcOffset": 2,
                "TimeZoneId": "Europe\/Copenhagen"
            }]
        },
        "Meta": {
            "@Version": "1.0.0",
            "Link": [{
                "@Href": "https:\/\/api.lufthansa.com\/v1\/references\/airports\/?limit=2&LHoperated=0&offset=0",
                "@Rel": "self"
            }, {
                "@Href": "https:\/\/api.lufthansa.com\/v1\/references\/airports\/?limit=2&LHoperated=0&offset=2",
                "@Rel": "next"
            }, {
                "@Href": "https:\/\/api.lufthansa.com\/v1\/references\/airports\/?limit=2&LHoperated=0&offset=1260",
                "@Rel": "last"
            }, {
                "@Href": "https:\/\/api.lufthansa.com\/v1\/references\/cities\/{cityCode}",
                "@Rel": "related"
            }, {
                "@Href": "https:\/\/api.lufthansa.com\/v1\/references\/countries\/{countryCode}",
                "@Rel": "related"
            }],
            "TotalCount": 1261
        }
    }
}
```

Then my **Java** co**de:
EDITTED:**

```
private void parseJson(String  result)
    {
        try {
            if (result!=null) {
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result).getJSONObject("AirportResource").getJSONObject("Airports");
                JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("Airport");
                for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
                {
                    String AirportCode = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("AAL");
                    String Latitude = arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Position").getJSONObject("Coordinate").getString("Latitude");
                    String Longitude =  arr.getJSONObject(i).getJSONObject("Position").getJSONObject("Coordinate").getString("Longitude");
                    System.out.println("Airport : " + AirportCode + " Latitude:  " + Latitude+
                            " Longitude : " + Longitude );
                }

            }
            else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,Config.POOR_NETWORK_CONNECTION, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }
        catch (JSONException r){
            System.out.println("ERROR PROB : "+  r);

        }
    }
```

***The exception am getting is :***

```
org.json.JSONException: No value for AirportResource
```

How can i parse this JSON kind of Data?

Comment: It seems your forgot about the `Airports` object in your code? `AirportResource (object) -> Airports (object) -> Airport (array)`

Comment: @xander, please help me with the edit

Comment: I suggest you to create POJOs for the JSON above and use a library such as Gson to parse it. You can exclude irrelevant data in the JSON string. Then parsing will be as simple as `gson.fromJson(json, AirportResource.class);`.

Comment: if logged `result` what you get ? try `System.out.println(result)` what you get ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will HOPEFULLY get you started.

```
private static void parseJson(JSONObject object) throws JSONException {
    if (object!=null) {
        JSONObject airportResource = object.getJSONObject("AirportResource");
        JSONObject airports = airportResource.getJSONObject("Airports");
        JSONArray airportArray = airports.getJSONArray("Airport");
        
        for (int i = 0 ; i < airportArray.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject airport = (JSONObject) airportArray.get(i);

            //System.out.println(airport);
            
            System.out.println("CityCode: " + airport.getString("CityCode"));
        }

    }
    else{
        //null

    }
}
```

The output will be:

> CityCode: AAL
>
> CityCode: AAR

Answer (score 1):

You didnt take the object of Airports. Inside Airports object is the Airport array and you are directly accessing it. Hence throwing  error.

```
JSONObject obj2 = obj.getJSONObject("Airports");
```

Now get Json Array from obj

```
JsonArray jsonarray= obj2.getJsonArray("Airport");
```

Use the for loop on jsonarray's length now.

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer.

Comment: Hello , can you please try to edit my code to your answer

Comment: edited it. I thought, Op should try the coding himself.

Comment: Hello, i have editted my code to `JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(result).getJSONObject("AirportResource").getJSONObject("Airports");`

Comment: DONT just copy and paste code. THINK about the soluation. you will NEVER get coding right if you have no idea what the code is trying to do. you have a few errors in the code though. ill work up an answer for you.

Comment: @IdrisStack You should play around with the Java debugger and analyse whats happening. Just set a breakpoint in your method and test some different JSON functions on the JSON string. It's pretty easy and may help you understand whats happening to write better code in the future. Also your problem has nothing to do with Android, so you could even create a small plain Java test project to only play around with JSON parsing (for faster debugging).

Answer (score -1):

I recommend using this [tool](http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/) to view and formate your JSON properly.

this is the result [image]

from here you could easily resolve your problem

```
JSONObject AirportResource= obj.getJSONObject("AirportResource");
JsonArray AirPorts= AirportResource.getJSONObject("Airports");
JsonArray jsonarray= AirPorts.getJsonArray("Airport");

      for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject obj= AirportResource.get(i); do sth with it
        obj.getString("key"); //do sth with it
       }
```

Comment: How is this different from his edited code in the question? Also `JsonArray AirPorts` should be of type `JSONObject `, but I guess that's a copy & pasre error. :)

Comment: I thought he does n't have a full understanding of JSON Structure.I read the question again and updated the answer. thanks for the feedback .@xander  :)